# How to use Spark to read all rows from hbase and post it to elastic search

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, mapreduce

In my current application, we are loading data to `elastic search` in the form of `json`documents, and this data is generated by processing the data taken from `HBASE`.
Currently we are using `mapreduce`for doing this, which fetch each row from `hbase`, process it and post the generated `json`file to `elastic search`.
Our data consists of millions of documents and it takes too much time to do this data loading.
Is there a more time efficient way to do the same using `Spark`.

Comment: The spark-elasticsearch module will do nothing more than the spark java api does in and of itself. Sure it will multithread fine, following spark partitions, and do proper socket connection reuse and all that, but it's not a magic bullet either. If you don't trust your code writing to elastic search, you may give spark a try, but otherwise it may not prove an interesting boost. Could you share a bit of code, the bit that writes to elasticsearch in particular ?

Comment: We have not used spark yet in our application. currently we use java elasticsearch client to post the data to elasticsearch index. The whole process runs using mapreduce as below.
Mapreduce(Read from HBASE-->process each row to create json document-->write the json document to ES index).
Is there a way to replace Mapreduce with SPARK in above process

Answer (score 0):

you can replace your `Mapreduce` with `spark` . you have to use the below configuration .

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster(master)
conf.set("es.index.auto.create", "true")
```

If you want to see the complete document [Apache spark with elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html#spark-write-meta-scala) 
Scala code with `elasticsearch` [Scala code for elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html#spark-write-meta-scala)
If you want to get the row from your `Hbase` then you check [spark-hbase-connector](https://github.com/nerdammer/spark-hbase-connector)